# Qual a diferença entre "mil" e "milhar"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, números

Eu suponho que:

- *Mil* é somente usado em números precisos (e.g., "duas mil pessoas");
- *Milhares* é somente usado em números imprecisos (e.g., "dezenas de milhares de pessoas"); e
- *Milhar* (a forma singular) é raramente usado.

Isso é correto? Se é mais ou menos assim, há exceções importantes?

Comment: Correções de gramática, ortografia e tags são bem vindas. Eu não sou um falante nativo (obviamente).

Comment: Interessante pontuar que "Milheiro" também é bastante utilizado em algumas indústrias (Ao menos na região sudeste do Brasil) com o significado de "Mil unidades". Muito utilizado por gráficas, para cartões de visita (Business Cards), flyers etc.

Answer (score 10):

A principal diferença é que *mil* é um quantificador (um caso específico de modificador) e *milhar* é um substantivo.

Ambas podem ser usadas para representar quantidades exatas, arredondadas ou apenas aproximadas/estimadas (ex: "duas mil pessoas" ou "dois milhares de pessoas"). Mas certamente, como mencionado na pergunta, a tendência principal é para a utilização de *mil* para valores exatos e arredondados, deixando o uso de *milhares* para valores mais incertos. Na escrita de um número por extenso, recorre-se sempre à palavra *mil* ("dois mil e quinze").

Para além disso, tanto uma como a outra podem ser figuradas para refletir apenas grandes quantidades.

---

#### English (by citation)

The main difference is that *mil* is a quantifier (a specific kind of modifier) and *milhar* is a noun.

Both can be used to represent exact, rounded or simply approximate quantities, (e.g. "duas mil pessoas" or "dois milhares de pessoas"). But indeed, as mentioned in the question, *mil* is much more often used to represent exact and rounded quantities, whereas *milhares* may be used for less certain amounts. When writing a number in words, we always rely on the word *mil* ("dois mil e quinze").

Furthermore, either one can be used as a figure of speech, to represent large quantities.

Comment: Obrigado. Na frase "dois mil", se "mil" é um adjetivo, é "dois" o substantivo modificado?

Comment: @Frank efetivamente, "dois" terá de ser modificado para o género do substantivo modificador (no exemplo, as pessoas).

Answer (score 4):

Ninguém diz "um milhar", "dois milhares" (ou é extremamente raro). Realmente "milhares" costuma ser usado para quantidades imprecisas.

Mas o substantivo também tem outro sentido, mais preciso, quando usado com artigo definido: *o milhar*. O milhar é o nome da quarta "casa" (de trás para frente) de um número de pelo menos quatro dígitos. Por exemplo, o número `3781`:

```
3.781
| ||| 
| ||uma unidade
| |oito dezenas 
| sete centenas
três milhares
```

Daí a expressão "acertei no milhar",  que rendeu [um clássico samba](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RFU0-bjNO4), com o sentido de "número de quatro dígitos" da loteria.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e a canção! Tem algo a dizer sobre a diferença com "mil"?

Comment: Acho que você intuiu certo, "mil" é mais usado para quantidades precisas, e "milhares" para quantidades imprecisas (embora dê pra fazer os dois termos representarem tanto quantidades precisas quanto imprecisas).