# "Um mil" or "Mil" or "Hum mil"?

Tags: gramática, números

What is the correct *pronunciation* and *type* to the number "1000"?

- Um mil
- Mil
- Hum Mil

---

Qual a *pronúncia* e *escrita* corretas para o número "1000"?

- Um mil
- Mil
- Hum Mil

Comment: Nunca ouvi  "hum mil". mas parece que [*há pessoas que preenchem cheques desta forma por receio de fraude: Hum mil reais.*](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070516113751AAiJIgV).

Comment: Related: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/224

Comment: Qual é o link que encontrou. "hum" existe apenas como [interjeição](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hum).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O número cardinal "1000" lê-se e escreve-se "mil" ou "um milhar", de forma similar a "100", que se lê "cem" ou "uma centena".

Relativamente a "hum mil" não vi ser usado em Portugal, até porque "hum" é uma interjeição", logo gramaticalmente incorrecto. "Mil? Hum!" estaria correcto do ponto de vista gramatical, mas o sentido é totalmente diferente.

A [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/532/105) de brasofilo mostra uma utilização de "Hum milhão" no preenchimento de um cheque.

---

The cardinal number "1000" is read and written as *mil* or *um milhar*, similarly to "100", which is read *cem* or *uma centena*.

Concerning *hum mil* I've never seen such a form in written in Portugal. Given that *hum* is an interjection it would be grammaticaly incorrect. *Mil? Hum?* is grammaticaly correct but it has a completely different meaning.

brasofilo's [answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/532/105) shows the use of *hum milhão* in a check (cheque).

Comment: I updated the question, to add more content.
You could edit the answer? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Oi, Américo, em Portugal é (ou foi) comum o uso de cheques bancários? No Brasil até hoje se usa, não tão extensivamente, mas não foi extinto como parece aqui na Espanha. (vide minha resposta)

Comment: @brasofilo Em Portugal o uso de cheques está em desuso, mas ainda circulam. Na altura em que eram frequentes não me apercebi desse uso de "Hum mil", eu nunca o escrevi. Mas, em comentário meu à pergunta, escrevi «Nunca ouvi "hum mil", mas parece que há pessoas que preenchem cheques desta forma por receio de fraude: Hum mil reais..».

Comment: Talvez devesse adicionar um link para a resposta do [@brasofilo](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/532/8) assim tornaria a sua resposta mais correta do que já é. Obrigado - Não estou só atrás de respostas, mas sim de coletar conteudo para o nosso querido site portuguese.SE :)

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Obrigado por me ter lembrado. Já editei a resposta.

Answer (score 8):

Vou esclarecer só o "Hum".
Isso é usado ao preencher cheques para indicar que queremos de fato dizer "1" e não "21". Para impedir que alguém modifique "Um mil" para "Vinte e Um mil", por exemplo.

[image]
<sub><sup>Imagem: Google Images, as partes censuradas são minhas, apesar de ser uma imagem de uma CPI do Congresso.</sup></sub>

Não sei se isso é reconhecido oficialmente pelos bancos ou se é um desses boatos que acabam se tornando fato.

Comment: O cheque não caiu, dá pra depositar novamente na minha conta? :D

Comment: @bfavaretto: sem problemas, vou pedir agora mesmo pra contabilidade providenciar :)(

Comment: Puts... eu olhando como se fosse Hum mil, e é Hum milhão... um dia quero poder assinar um cheque desse valor e com fundos...

Comment: @LucasMotta, puxa, acabo de me dar conta, dá pra converter um cheque escrito "Hum Mil" pra "Hum Milhão" com certa facilidade, lol

Comment: @brasofilo No entanto valores assim "requerem" um "procedimento maior" acredito eu.

Comment: @brasofilo parece que eles usam o # no começo e no final também como segurança contra este tipo de problema

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: oh, yeah! Mas tá assim de gente que usa "password" como senha :)

Comment: @brasofilo não entendi se isto se refere ao primeiro ou ao meu segundo comentário, kk - desculpe a minha ignorância no assunto :) - Só pra dar enfase, o `#` é usado assim por exemplo `#Um mil#` acredito eu (nunca usei cheque... felizmente rs)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , agora não tenho mais certeza, interpretação livre :) Provavelmente vc ainda não comprou um carro caro ou casa, eu tb não, jjjj Nesses casos, o gerente faz um cheque administrativo, garantia do banco, segurança na transação

Comment: Pelo que eu me lembro da época que eu preenchia cheques, o `#` era usado nos números, e não no texto. Exemplo `#1957905,42#`, entretanto nunca preenchi um cheque de valor tão alto assim, meus cheques eram mais parecidos com esse daqui: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eMqve.jpg :)