# Why "milhões" take a preposition after it?

Tags: números, preposições

In English, it is correct to say:

> five dollars
>   five thousand dollars
>   five million dollars
>   five billion dollars

And in Portuguese, these are:

> cinco doláres
>   cinco mil doláres
>   cinco milhões **de** doláres
>   cinco bilhões **de** doláres

So, it is not correct to say:

> <s>cinco milhões dólares</s>

Why is it "milhões de" (with the preposition) starting with millions?

Comment: Yes, it is weird indeed... Especially if you think of measurements, such as _centímetros_ and _quilómetros_ where the use of **de** wouldn't make any sense. However, there is: _1 quilo **de** batatas_ which is 1kg **of** potatoes...

Comment: "cinco mil" = "cinco milhares", and the latter takes the preposition too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The words *milhão*, *bilhão* (informal Brazilian Portuguese) and *bilião* (European Portuguese for a million times *milhões*, Brazilian Portuguese for a thousand times *milhões*), as well as subsequent numeral quantities, are **nouns** rather than quantifiers.

We may qualify another noun with *mil* (because it's a quantifier, [related question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/229/84)), but immediately adjacent nouns do not naturally occur in the Portuguese language, which makes "um milhão euros" incorrect. Instead, a *locução adjetiva* (phrasal adjective) takes place by joining them with the preposition designed for a relationship of number/amount/matter, which is *de*. Therefore, the same preposition can be used for combining a concept with amounts:

> O novo edifício recebeu uma bolsa de três milhões de euros para o seu financiamento.
>
> O camião transportava grandes quantidades de tintas.

Comment: Aqui no Brasil pelo menos, não há nada de informal em "bilhões" e "trilhões". E se por aqui você falar "milhão de milhões", será algo algo tão estranho e bizarro quanto falar "centena de cens" ao invés de "dez mil" ou falar "milhar de milhares" ao invés de "milhão", vão perguntar de que planeta você veio.

Comment: 1. O dicionário Priberam define-a como sendo informal,

Comment: 2. Não é correto falar em "milhão de milhões", certamente. Obrigado, pensei numa coisa e escrevi outra. Vou corrigir.

Comment: @E_net4 Fui lá no priberam conferir. Na minha opinião, isto é um erro da parte deles. Já vi a grafia "bilhões" até em documentos públicos e leis orçamentárias, e claramente se referindo ao número 1000000000. Entretanto falar "mil milhões" deste lado do Atlântico soa como algo bizarro e ninguém por aqui falaria uma expressão destas. Aliás, segundo [a wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalas_curta_e_longa) isto é algo que difere entre as duas versões do português. Para piorar, "bilião" em Portugal é "trilhão" no Brasil, enquanto que "trilião" em Portugal é "quinquilhão" no Brasil.

Comment: Bem sei que estes numerais funcionam de forma diferente entre os dois países. Acerca disso, não posso fazer nada. O assunto do _bilião_ e do _bilhão_ é que é mais delicado, e não vou quer aprofundar o tema aqui.

Comment: @VictorStafusa "quinquilhão" é bem bizarro em Portugal até pelo seu duplo sentido :D

Comment: @VictorStafusa achei que isso só acontecia no espanhol...

Comment: @JorgeB.- sempre tenho lido e ouvido *quintilhão*, não *quinquilhão*.

Answer (score -1):

O sistema americano, da USA, prevaleceu, mesmo na Europa. um milhão de milhões, aceita-se como um bilião. Não concordo, mas é assim. Antigamente, seria milhão de milhões, um bilião, mas não se usa mais.

Comment: Parece-me que te escapou algo na pergunta. A pergunta é, porque é que se diz "um milhão **de** dólares" e não simplesmente "um milhão dólares", sem o ***de***.

Comment: O sistema de numeração americano considera "one billion" como sendo o nosso mil milhões (10 elevado a 9), e os dicionários portugueses de hoje continuam a definir _bilião_ como sendo um milhão de milhões (10 elevado a 12). Com certeza houve alguma confusão aqui, porque a resposta não está coerente.